# Passing a list in place of sql parameter to a stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql

Is there a way to pass a list object as a parameter of a stored procedure?

for eg,

```
List<class1> Allobj = new List<class1>();
// assume Allobj .Count=5,(5 class1 objects)
```

now calling a stored procedure as

```
intResult = _helper.ExecuteNonQuery(base.Transaction, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "usp_InsertpurchaseEnquirydetails", Allobj );
```

or is there any other way to pass a list( atleast adding to a multidimensional sqlparameter array?

If possible how to pass and also how to iterate it from the stored procedure?

Comment: **[This article](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html)** is a great resource that runs through your options for working with collections in SQL-Server.

Comment: Are you writing **SQL** (structured query language) and really mean Microsoft **SQL Server** (the actual product) by this? If not: **what** database system is this for?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `TableValueParameters`. Starting from SqlServer 2008 this feature is added. It will help you to pass a `DataTable` as  a parameter.

Check out [Table-Valued Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx) in msdn

Answer (score 1):

You could use Table value parameter to pass a table or list to SQL stored procedures

Steps in brief:

1) Create a table value parameter in SQL server management studio

2) Define a parameter as created table value parameter (it should be readonly)

3) Set the C# sp parameter type to System.Data.SqlDbType.Structured

4) Pass your list as a CLR DataTable to stored procedure

The bellow link is a complete code example:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/39161/C-and-Table-Value-Parameters